# Data class serialization with blank string in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a data class in Django using the rest framework, that has a string field and a serializer for it.

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    string_field:str


class FooSerializer(DataclassSerializer):
    class Meta:
        dataclass = Foo
```

My problem is that, if the string_field is blank, the serializer cannot be validated.
The JSON I am calling with:

```
{'string_field': ''}
```

And the error:

```
{'string_field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')]}
```

Declaring the fields in the serializer and not using a data class is a solution, but I'd prefer to use the data class way if its possible. In my project I am using Django 3.0.5, Python 3.8 and 3.11 of the rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `allow_blank=True` in the `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. My problems is that the project uses data class serializers and I want to keep that pattern. With that I couldn't find out how to do this.

Comment: You're using rest framework, so this is the correct solution ... also, `Dataclass` I assume is a custom class here, so you would have to update your question with that class definition and info on how you are serializing there or let us know what package you are using to do it.

Comment: Ohh, thats my bad.
Its DataclassSerializer, it is part of the rest framework. I also missed the @dataclass decorator, from the Foo class